# Node.js - "Cannot find module 'module.js' "

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, require

I'm using Heroku and I get this error..

```
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188366+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'module1.js'
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188370+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188371+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188371+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188372+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:42:15)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188373+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188374+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188374+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188375+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-10T03:34:11.188375+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

**app.js**

```
/**CUSTOM_MODULES**/

var module1 = require('module1.js');

/**MODULES_END**/
```

**module1.js**

```
function module1(){
    //My code
}

module.exports = module1;
```

module1.js is in the same directory as my app.js.

I have tried countless things but nothing seems to work.

I have tried:

```
 var module1 = require('module1.js');
 var module1 = require('./module1.js');
 var module1 = require('../module1.js');
 var module1 = require('module1');
```

**package.json : app.js**

```
{
  "name": "nano-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8",  
    "module1": "0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**package.json : module1**

```
 {
  "name": "module1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "get something",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "sergey"
  },
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "_id": "module1@0.0.0",
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "dc9b96f8a43b596bf735da4d2004ba410429bde0",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/module1/-/module1-0.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "_from": "module1@latest",
  "_npmVersion": "1.3.11",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "sergey-user",
    "email": "aaa@mail.ru"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "sergey-user",
      "email": "aaa@mail.ru"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {},
  "_shasum": "dc9b96f8a43b596bf735da4d2004ba410429bde0",
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/module1/-/module1-0.0.0.tgz"
}
```

**directory**

```
_server
    .git
    node_modules
        .bin
        express
        module1
            index.js
            package.json
        mysql
        node-mysql
        node-uuid
        socket.io
    package.json
    server.js
```

Answer (score 7):

Try var module1 = require('./module1');

Comment: Didn't work. `module1.js` is not in any extra folders, same directory as app.js

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on this if it helps. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/
Follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, rather a method I haven't done or so

Answer (score 1):

install `npm -g` and try again afterwords.

Comment: Tried npm install -g and keep trying different `require()` directory, so far still not working

Answer (score 1):

Adding your module as a dependency to your application would resolve this issue. To achieve that try the below command.

`npm install module1 --save`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did this, changed name to index.js and put in module1 folder, it finally recognized the module1 folder (thank you), but it seems to not initiate index.js because now it's calling an error on "module1 is not a function" in my app.js

Comment: It is the `module.js` I have posted. I also switched the module1 package.json from `"main": "github.js"` to `"main": "index.js"`

Comment: Can you post your directory structure if possible?

Comment: Is it the package.json file?

Comment: No. I meant the directory/file hierarchy

Comment: Not sure what you required, but I posted it at bottom

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying everything without any success, updating node helped (v10.3.1 -> v12.13.1).